# facing problem in updating Angular CLI in mac

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

current Angular version  :

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.20
Node: 14.17.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.20
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.20
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.20
@schematics/angular          8.3.20
@schematics/update           0.803.20
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

So I tried to update it with:

```
ng update @angular/cli@^10 @angular/core@^10
```

I got Error:

> The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable
> version. Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
> Installing packages for tooling via npm. Installed packages for
> tooling via npm. ***Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any
> changes before updating.***

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core -- next
```

I got same issue

> The installed Angular CLI version is older than the latest stable
> version. Installing a temporary version to perform the update.
> Installing packages for tooling via npm. Installed packages for
> tooling via npm***. Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any
> changes before updating.***

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
```

Here I got Error :

> Repository is not clean. Update changes will be mixed with
> pre-existing changes. Using package manager: 'npm' Collecting
> installed dependencies... An unhandled exception occurred: ***Could not
> find package.json See
> "/private/var/folders/3d/15mk70f109l87p410dyq_ntc0000gn/T/ng-2pBTiN/angular-errors.log"***
> for further details.

I have MacOS
then I deleted NodeModule and package-lock.json from Users/User file
and here is what I have done so far based on recommendations I have found here but I still get this error

```
 ~~ sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli

 ~~ sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

 ~~ sudo npm cache clean --force

 ~~ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

But still Angular version is not updated , When I did

```
ng version
```

- Still it is 8.3.20

Comment: Did you see the error message: Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating. Did you do that?

Comment: How to do that in mac?